# Why is the raster information No Data value set to -1.#IND?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, grass-gis

I have a couple rasters that have been atmospherically corrected using the "landsat.toar" tool in Grass. When these rasters are output and I open up their properties in ArcCatalog, the NoData Value under Raster Information is "-1.#IND". Any idea what this means? It also doesn't respond like normal NoData values, as I can't use tools like "Is Null" to identify it.

Answer (score 2):

`-1.#IND` returns when an incorrect mathematical operation is done, like dividing by zero or the square root of a negative number. Maybe GRASS tool used standard deviation of NoData set as -9999.

I suggest two solutions:

1. Check your source NoData value, if it is negative, change it to positive.
2. If you cannot change it or if it's positive, you can convert your output into array, substitute the value using `numpy.when()` and back again to raster.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm thinking the problem is that GRASS uses a NoData value of NaN, which maybe Arc doesn't like or handle in the same way?